# Redirecting Issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax

Let's say I have a website www.mysite.com and I want it to be a multilingual site. Following are the things I wanna achieve :-

**1.** When a user visits my website, I want to fetch the user's country's ISO code. Let's say the ISO is "FR".
   Now I want the user to be redirected to www.mysite.fr

In case the ISO address can't be fetched, the user will be redirected to www.mysite.com

Now I have used  the dll from this site http://ipaddressextensions.codeplex.com/ and used their method which is something like
  iso3066code(). BUT I am not able to fetch ISO code based on a user's IP address. What is the best method to fetch the ISO code anyway??

**2.** I have a differenet master page for different countries. Like for France there is  France.master, for Germany there is Germany.master, etc.
   What I want is that firstly the ISO Code of the user should be fetched, then the user should be redirected to the site corresponding to the ISO
   AND want the corresponding master to load.

Here's a scenario:-

A user from France opens my website by typing "www.mysite.com". Now I want to show the user my site's contents in French so I want him to be redirected to 
"www.mysite.fr" AND want the France.master to load for all the pages. What I am doing is check the "Top level domain name" entered by user which is "com" in this case, then I fetch the ISO code 
 then if ISO exists, user is redirected to "www.mysite.fr"

IN CASE, ISO cant be fetched , "www.mysite.com" will only be opened for the user.

**3.** How do I redirect the user?? Response.Redirect("http://www.mysite.fr") is failing and giving errors like :-

"Page is not redirecting properly"  I tried changing it to Response.Redirect("http://www.mysite.fr", false)
    and Response.Redirect("http://www.mysite.fr", true). This didn't work.

**4.** www.mysite.com and www.mysite.fr aren't two different websites.Just that when is it www.mysite.com, English content will be shown on the website.
   When it is "www.mysite.fr", French content can be seen inside the website.

What I did was :-

In the Global.asax file :-

I tried fetching ISO code using that dll above from the site ipaddressextensions. Then I created this Application("UserISO") variable in Global.asax file.((Is this a good approach?)) 
I needed to make it because I wanted to use this global variable within my Global file itself..In some user defined method.
 Then I am setting master page name in a cookie and using this cookie to change master page dynamically for every content page in the Page_PreInit() event.
and lastly I am redirecting the user with " Response.Redirect("http://www.mysite.fr", false)". This response.redirect doesnt work!

Now, AM I on the right path?? I am super confused over how to actually make it work! :( 
How do multilingual site redirect their users? Where can I learn about all this ? I have tried and tried and tried but this just won't work!

Lastly, there are not really any domain names set for the site as of now. Running it using the IP address set in the IIS.
So how do I test my site. How do I really go about it. Am I following the correct approach at all??

Please direct me to the right path. ANY help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @ILoverMusic, I think, you should use Mike Atlas's advice if you don't want to distribute your site between regional servers.

Comment: @Acoolaum :: If only I could change the requirements... HAVE to implement that only

Answer (score 2):

Belgium has 3 official languages, you can't find my language by just looking at the ip address or the domain.

The best way to find the language of a visitor is to check the language of his browser. You can find it in Request.Userlanguages.

Comment: : Whatever is Belgium's default language, content will be shown in that. I need to use the ISO code :(( If ISO is not there in the IP address, then default website will run. What now? Help needed implementing this please.

Comment: Not only that, but if the browser is set to French, why redirect to .fr site when the visitor could be from Haiti, or Quebec, for example?

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this. It's really frustrating when you try to assume what language the user speaks. You're bound to get it wrong for someone eventually. Put some small flag icons or the language name choices on your main page in a highly visible place, and let your visitors chose what site/language they want to browse in.

Facebook's main sign in page is a great example of this.

Edit: The best you could probably do is to use the [HTTP1.1 Header Accept-Language](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) as a hint, but even then I think you should push back on this requirement of your project.

Comment: : Its a requirement. I HAVE to implement that way! Yes there ARE gonna be choices for the user. Could you please help me out how do I go about it??

Comment: Well, you also asked to be directed on the right path. I answered your question as such. If your requirements are forcing you to do this, then look at the rest of the answers.

Comment: @ Mike:: Thanks. Yeah I know that would be better. But I asked about better way to code or some other way to implement all this. Can't change what is required.

Answer (score 0):

You get redirect error because the .fr site is probably the same site as .com, but session cookies are only valid for a certain domain which means that Session_OnStart() is invoked on the redirect as well. One way to circumvent this is to override the redirect/ip-lookup somehow, maybe send in a querystring or a specific landing page that you can identify:

www.site.fr/?overrideredirect=true
www.site.fr/redirected.aspx -> which then redirects back to / after Session_OnStart

In order to choose the right master page, you could probably identify which host that was requested and from that override master page in your global.asax, perhaps in the BeginRequest event.

Comment: : I am doing all that coding in the Begin_request event only. Are you suggesting that it should be in Session_Start event?? Why so?

Comment: Because you only want to do it on their first visit of course. Begin_Request is invoked on every request.

Comment: : Oh ok.. So I just need to write the code in the Session_Start method then? I first put this code in Application_Start but it said Response and REquest objects are not available in that event so implemented in BEgin_Request. Ok I ll change that. Also, is creating that Application variable the right thing to do? Any negative effects of that? I wanted to use the ISO Code in this other user defined method in my Global file itself. There was no other way to define global variables in global.asax file. What harm can it cause anyway? I wont be using this Application variable any place else

Comment: I think you need to start with studying the basic of an ASP.NET application, you don't seem to have any clue on how it works. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178583.aspx is a good start

Comment: well yes I AM new to it. Thanks for the link